# Algoritmo implementando una función

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]soy nuevo en Javascript, tuve un examen en el cuál no pude resolver el siguiente código, ya que siempre que corro el test el mensaje mostrado es `TypeError` construcciones no es una función. Lo que se me pide es:

> En este ejercicio debemos implementar la función construccionCasas() la cual nos va a determinar
> cuantas casas se pueden construir según la cantidad de bolsas de cemento que dispongamos.
> La función recibirá por parámetro la cantidad de bolsas de cemento que dispongamos y dentro de la misma debe retornar otra función pasándole por parámetros la cantidad de casas que queramos construir.
> INFORMACION:
> 10 bolsas de cemento equivalen a 1 casa
> Si la cantidad de casas que recibo es 0 o menor debe retornar "Por favor ingresar cuantas casas quieres construir"
> // -Si la cantidad de bolsas de cemento no equivalen a 1 casa debe retornar "No se puede construir casas con esa cantidad de bolsas"
> Si la cantidad de casas sobrepasa la cantidad de bolsas de cemento necesarias para construir esas casas... ej: bolsas de cemento = 10 y casas = 2 debe retornar `Solo puedes construir esta cantidad de casas: 1`
> Si la cantidad de casas es igual a la cantidad de bolsas de cemento necesarias para construir esas casas debe retornar true

EJEMPLOS:

```
let casas = construccionCasas(100)
casas(10) => 10 me devolveria true

let casas = construccionCasas(0)

casas(10) => 'No se puede construir casas con esa cantidad de bolsas'
```

Mi código hasta ahora, después de borrar y volver a probar:

```js
function construccionCasas(bolsas) {
    let construcciones = function(casas)  {
    casas = bolsas/10;
    if(casas == 0) return "Por favor ingresar cuantas casas quieres construir";
    if(casas < 1) return "No se puede construir casas con esa cantidad de bolsas";
    if(casas >= 1) 
    casas = Math.floor(bolsas/10) 
    return "Puedes construir " + casas + " casas";
  }
  return construcciones();
}
//let construcciones = new  construccionCasas();
console.log(construccionCasas(12));
console.log(construccionCasas(1));
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No entiendo porque tu funcion contiene una variable con una funcion.. que quisiste hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  function construccionCasas(bolsasCemento){
    var deBolsasACasas = bolsasCemento / 10;
    return function(casas){
        if(casas <= 0) return "Por favor ingresar cuantas casas construir"
        if(bolsasCemento < 10) return "No se pueden contruir casas con esa cantidad de bolsas"
        if(casas > deBolsasACasas) return `Solo puedes contruir esta cantidad de casas: ${Math.floor(deBolsasACasas)}`
        if(casas % deBolsasACasas === 0) return true
    }
}

console.log(construccionCasas(10)(1)); // el segundo parentesis el es numero de casas, que es parametro de la funcion que retorna constuccionCasas
// que a su vez retorna los mensajes que se piden en la consigna
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Si genial, ya veo la diferencia con mi código. Gracias, aprendiendo de mis errores.

Comment: si la respuesta te sirvio marcala como "util". Saludos